# イテレータから連続する2つ要素を舐める

Tags: python, python3

以下の `with_next()` のように、不定長のイテレータから連続する2つの要素を順番に取得するループを、出来る限りシンプルな、行数の少ないコードで実現するにはどうすればいいでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

```py
def with_next(it):
    it = iter(it)
    prev = next(it)
    for n in it:
        yield prev,n
        prev = n

import itertools
for a in with_next(itertools.count()):
    print(a)
    if a[0]>10:
        break
```

Comment: [Itertools Resipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) の `pairwise` 関数が参考になるかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。そのものズバリの関数はなさそうですね。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

more-itertoolsのwindowedをお探しではありませんか？
https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.windowed

```
import itertools
from more_itertools import windowed
for a in windowed(itertools.count(), 2):
    print(a)
    if a[0]>10:
        break
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。コレを探していました。

Answer (score 3):

#### <頂いたコメントから>`itertools.tee()` を使う方法

頂いたコメントから `itertools.tee()` を使って以下のように書くことにしました。
ありがとうございました。

```
import itertools
it1, it2 = itertools.tee(it)
for a,b in zip(it1, itertools.islice(it2, 1, None)):
    ...
```

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。訂正しました。